# Does spring integration support AMQP with ActiveMq

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-integration, amqp

I am new to the MOM.

I want to connect to ActiveMQ using AMQP from my application. 
Also I want to use Spring Integration for connecting to the ActiveMq.

I see example of AMQP for rabbitMQ  but I am not able to find any example for ActiveMq.

Is it not possible to do with Spring  Integration ?

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't possible.

> ActiveMQ supports the AMQP 1.0 protocol which is an OASIS standard.

Where RabbitMQ and hence Spring Integration AMQP adapters support  0.9.1.

Those Spec versions are very different.

You should try tu use ActiveMQ JMS API over its AMQP. And finally Spring Integration JMS adapters.

Comment: Does spring plan to move to Oasis standard?

Comment: @raffian, please, share the link to be sure what you mean.

Comment: I was referring to your comment: `Spring Integration AMQP adapters support 0.9.1.`, is this merely current state? Does spring plan on supporting AMQP 1.0?

Comment: The main AMQP implementation for Spring Integration is RabbitMQ. So, we definitely will take a look to AMQP 1.0 when RabitMQ will do that first of all. AFAIK all AMQP 1.0 vendors provide JMS bridge for that, so we really may not taking a look to that at all, because JMS is there for awhile.

Comment: ActiveMQ does not support AMQP 1.0 from it's JMS library. Non the less, it should be possible to use Apache Qpid Proton (http://qpid.apache.org/proton/) to connect to ActiveMQ via AMQP 1.0 using JMS from Spring integration.

Comment: Yes, that's correct comment. More info is here: http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html

Comment: @ArtemBilan If I wanted to start an in memory broker to test my spring integration configuration via a unit test, is there an example you may know of I can look at? I've had no luck googling or searching on github yet :(

Comment: No,there is no such an embedded RabbitMQ solution

Comment: I am aware there is no embedded rabbitmq broker, but is there not another broker solution like qpid or apollo that could be used? Or am I missing the fact that this is very much a rabbitmq solution. Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: @user3465651 the best way to run integration tests against RabbitMQ is to use https://www.testcontainers.org/